# Get the content of outputField

Tags: visualforce, email, formula, email-template, translation-workbench

I have a global picklist with different translations (Translation Workbench). I am changing the language in an email template so that the picklist value gets translated. As far as I know, the only way to dynamically translate the picklist value in an email template is by using the tag apex:outputField, something like:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!recipient.EmailGreeting__c}"/>
```

This is working correctly, meaning that I am getting the translation of the pick-list value. In addition, I need to uppercase the EmailGreeting__c value. It needs to change from dear to DEAR. I am doing the following:

```
{!UPPER(<apex:outputField value="{!recipient.EmailGreeting__c}"/>)}
```

But I am getting an error message:

```
Error: Syntax error. Found '<'
```

The way I am following to get/capture the content of `<apex:outputField value="{!recipient.EmailGreeting__c}"/` does not seem to be supported in salesforce. Is there any other way to dor it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your formula function *inside* the merge field for your `<apex:outputText>`.

Joy:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!UPPER(...)}" />
```

No Joy:

```
{!UPPER(<apex:outputField value="{!...}" />)}
```

Comment: I am coding it as follows: <apex:outputField value="{!UPPER(recipient.EmailGreeting__c)}" />. However, I get an error message: Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Comment: I do not think it will work. Because the apex:outputField does the translation. So the field EmailGreeting__c content can be manipulated after it outputs it. I hope that makes sense.